# Disable XSS and HTML Sanitization in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, xss

I'm having an issue where when I have the contents of my rich text editor saved into the database using activerecord the html content is stripped of the html contents (I think it fires html_safe on it). I tried overriding the html_safe method on the content string, but nothing works.

```
content = "<p>hello</p>"
@article.content = content
puts @article.content # "<p>hello</p>"
@article.save
puts @article.content # "<>hello</>"
```

How can you override the html stripping capabilities in activerecord for a particular column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue to this problem was nothing todo with Rails or the XSS stripping. The code that I had was modifying a string and then saving the results elsewhere which was causing the original input to be changed. I solved the problem by using `string.dup` to copy over the original string so that I wasn't affected.

Answer (score 1):

As [frank blizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532102/frank-blizzard) already said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951062/disable-xss-and-html-sanitization-in-rails-3/6953341#6953341), you make your self vulnerable two XSS-Attacks.

But if you trust your authors, that this columns are safe two display, you can do something like this in your `Article` model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def content
    attributes[:content].html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: The html_safe method is what causes the stripping in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `raw(string)` method, but it would make you vunlerable against XSS attacks.
Another option would be taking a deeper look into [markdown](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet).

Comment: The issue is that the raw method is a helper-level function and it does not have anything todo with how it gets saved with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score -3):

There should be an option for this.

I encourage you to take a look at the docs of the rich text editor that you are using.