# Get Rails 3 to sanitize output by default instead of escaping it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, xss

By default, Rails 3 escapes strings you output directly – e.g., `<%= '<h1>' %>` renders as `&lt;h1&gt;`

Because of this I have to annoyingly do this a lot:

```
<%= sanitize @post.body %>
```

Is there any way I can make this the default? I.e., I want this:

```
<%= @post.body %>
```

to be equivalent to:

```
<%= sanitize @post.body %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= h @post.body %>
```

as it is by default

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951062/disable-xss-and-html-sanitization-in-rails-3

Comment: That question is about disabling HTML escaping entirely. I want to replace HTML escaping with HTML sanitization, so it doesn't help me

Answer (score 2):

```
class ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
  def concat(value)
    super(ERB::Util.h(value))
  end
  alias << concat
  def dirty?
    false
  end
end
```

Have fun being XSS'd. Do not use in production. This does disable XSS protection entirely and you can't even explicitly tell a piece of data is unsafe. I'd rather do

```
class Post
  def body_with_raw
    body_without_raw.html_safe
  end
  alias_method_chain :body, :raw
end
```

or even

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.html_safe(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      name = attribute + "with_raw"
      before = attribute + "without_raw"
      define_method name do
        before.html_safe
      end
      alias_method_chain attribute, "raw"
    end
  end
end
```

so you can

```
class Post
  html_safe :body
end
```

Comment: I'm not trying to *disable* escaping; I'm trying to *replace* it with sanitization. Does my answer make sense / work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Tass' answer, I feel like this might work (but I'm not sure):

```
class ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
  def concat(value)
    if dirty? || value.html_safe?
      super(value)
    else
      # super(ERB::Util.h(value)) # this is what Rails does by default
      super(ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(value))
    end
  end
end
```